# Is my app suitable for converting to the "fragment design paradigm"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am wondering if my app is suitable for converting to fragments.

I have worked through several tutorials: android Shakespeare, vogella, and the excellent lunchlist. They share the same design, a list on the left side, “information” on the right side. All of the entries in the list have the same corresponding view type  on the right side  (many-to-one).

My app would be a departure from this: each entry in the list on the left side would correspond to a different view type on the right. There would be 10 entries on the left side, with 10 different views on the right (one-to-one).

Could I persevere with fragments, and do a lot of FragmentTransaction management or should I keep my app as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use fragments because:

1. Fragments are a core part of the longer-term trajectory for Android
2. Using them now will help you understand how to use them, so future projects are easier
3. Implementing fragments isn't that complicated, so why not?
4. Having different view types in your detail fragment is compatible with using fragments
5. If you use fragments in the app now, it'll make it easier to tweak the app later for different devices types & orientations

Comment: Thanks, point 4 is what I was looking for. I'll convert my app.